# content_script not loaded when background sends message

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension, my background script sends a message to the content_script which loads as part of a page.
The content_script doesn't seem to receive the message and I think it's because it's not loaded when the background script fires off the message. If I put a 5sec delay in the background script before sending the message, then it works. Is there another way to check if the content_script is ready before firing off the message?

manifest

```
"manfiest_version": 2,
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches" : [ "https://example.com/*" ],
  "js": ["content_scripts.js"]
}
],
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  console.log('sending msg to tab '+tabs[0].id);
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message: "hello"}, function(response) {});  
});
```

content_script.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('content_script received msg');
  }
);
```

Comment: The background/event page is a separate hidden page that runs when the browser starts your user profile. As you can see it's not related to any tabs or content scripts. Simply initiate messaging from your content script.

Comment: Only the BG (background.js) knows when to send something to the CS ( content_script), not the other way around. But maybe what you're saying is, I should have CS send a msg to BG first to let it know it's ready and then have BG respond or send a message later when it's ready

Comment: I was hoping for a way for the BG to be able to detect whether the CS is ready or not. Maybe if it doesn't receive a response, it could wait and send again

Comment: Well of course you can put the code into a function and retry when `response` is falsy.